# what gauge two core cable to use inside headphones

Tags: headphones

This is my first post so excuse me if wording is wrong, I have a set of headphones and want to replace the cable that connects the left headphone speaker to the right, its a very thin black two core wire, copper and red, it measures 0.77mm, I haven't a clue about gauge size, so if someone could answer that for me, and recommend a cable that would be a bit more flexible over time to save breakages in future.

Thanks

Gary

Comment: Is it really that hard to look into a list of wire sizes and determine the nearest bigger size?

Answer (score 0):

The amount of current passing through those wires is very small. Any wire that is sufficiently large to support itself mechanically is more than adequate for the electrical requirements. The primary issue is finding wire that is very flexible for use in that particular application. Look for something small but FLEXIBLE.

We don't know where you are or what gauge measurement standard you use. But I am in North America and I would limit my search to something around 25-30 AWG.  Anything smaller will be too fragile, and anything much larger won't be flexible enough.

Comment: Hi Richard, I'm in you UK, I should have said sorry, I was thinking something similar, and I'm going to go for 28 flexible silicone two core. And many thanks yourself and PlasmaHH for answering